# How do i get friends from facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

In my application I need to get facebook friends. I wrote code for that but  the result coming like this,

response:{"data":[]}

my code is:

```
    public void getFriendsInformation() {
            mAsyncRunner.request("/me/friends", new RequestListener() {
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                    String json = response;
                    try {
                        // Facebook Profile JSON data
                        JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                        Log.v("TAG_KK",""+profile);
  //result is {"data":[]}



                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //new BackGroundTask2().execute();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                                    Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                                    Object state) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I get friends from facebook.

Comment: please any one help me out

Comment: It seems that you are using much older fb sdk version, This is version 2 i believe. They have released the version 4 few weeks back. Also they changed several permissions/ accessiblities when comes to v2 to v4. Try the latest sdk version please.

Comment: @Davidjhons i am using  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'

Comment: @Davidjhons could you please suggest me which one i need to use...pleasee

Comment: it could be , but "mAsyncRunner" came with v2 :) It may still support though.

Comment: @learnerandroid If people would not have to read through your repeated begging (no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) ), they would have more time answering questions (including yours).

Comment: please read here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Answer (score 1):

Call this url to get friendlist

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="your accesstoken";